# Stamp PDF and Optionally Password Protect

Tags: php, pdf, centos

I have a pdf which I need to programatically stamp with a username and email address before distribution.

Also I have been sent a pdf in the past which has required me to give a username and password to get it to open.

Are there any libraries that can do this ?

I'm using CentOs with PHP for the server.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do that with [GhostScript](https://ghostscript.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Use.html?highlight=password#spdfpassword-password), at least the password protection (look for *-sOwnerPassword* and *-sUserPassword* in the [documentation](https://ghostscript.readthedocs.io/en/latest/VectorDevices.html?highlight=password#pdf-file-output-pdfwrite)).

I have used it in the past for server side processing of PS and PDF files and worked fine, although it's a bit difficult get started with it.

Comment: The documentation has moved, I believe the new link would be [this one](http://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.16/Readme.htm#Ps2pdf) finally taking you [here](http://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.16/Ps2pdf.htm), but those link are version specific... So the starting point for the entire documentation should be [here](http://www.ghostscript.com/Documentation.html)